# Laptop speakers + additional speaker

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

Is it possible to play sound through laptop speakers and additional speaker at the same time ? I have Ubuntu 11.10 on Lenovo IdeaPad Y570 and http://uk.jbl.com/jbl-product-detail-uk/on-tour-micro-2.html . I will appreciate a guide on how to do it, in case it is possible.

Thanks in advance !

Best regards,

Pressko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still interesting, then i can provide an existing example that this is possible.

I have an [Asus N53SV X5MSV](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Asus-N53SV-Notebook.43709.0.html) laptop and also searched for kind of that solution (actually I searched how to make different sound o/p from these outputs: headsets and built in speakers).

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. To make work both of them at the same time with the same output do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer 
open it
```

There will be an option to mute/unmute speakers/headsets. This worked for me. And I don't use usb headsets, just S/PDIF jack headsets and built in speakers.

**UPD231222**
I have tried this on Asus TUF A15 FA506IV with Endeavour OS rolling, and it still works like a charm. Sadly, but default `pavucontrol` doesn't have such neat option.

[image: gnome-alsamixer]

Comment: Updated  to Ubuntu  16.04 and this tweak doesn't work there.  Looking for    solution...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is a hardware switch integrated with the headphone jack that prevents this. It has nothing to do with your OS. If you were really determined to do it, you could disassemble and modify the jack, but that's outside the scope of the original question.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector#Switch_contacts) Wikipedia article for more info.

Comment: 10X man :) I guess that's right .